# Padding appears on chrome browser only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

I see some white space appearing on my website: http://goo.gl/hTyrj

It appears only on using chrome browser not firefox and IE. Try opening the link in various browsers (including chrome), you will understand what the problem is.

I tries to inspect element in chrome. But I cannot recognize what it is.

Can anyone please guide me. Whether it's some problem with CSS or some script in head region?

**UPDATE:** See the pictures below:

**CHROME:**

[image: extra white space in chrome browser]

**FIREFOX:**

[image: firefox]

Comment: For me it looks fine, where exactly the problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe it will solve the issue. Could you check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also see a difference in your site between Chrome and IE10.

After inspection, I can see that for some reason this snippet causes some issues:

```
#nav-container {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```

A little bit further, I can see this snippet:

```
#nav-container {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-width: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f5f5f5));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #f5f5f5);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #ffffff 0%, #f5f5f5 100%);
  background: -moz-gradient(center top, #ffffff 0%, #f5f5f5 100%);
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

Set the margin-bottom of both snippets to 0 and the result will be as expected!